# it this expression possible in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object data. in data, we have created the following array:

```
data = {items: [{ "4","5","6" }, {"7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"}]}
console.log("items:", items[0]);
```

but when use in js I get the error

```
Unexpected token ','
```

so can I use that code as an object?

Comment: `{"4","5","6"}` is invalid. Either use `[ "4","5","6" ]` (Array) or `{ a:"4", b:"5", c:"6" }` (Object).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid javascript object. Objects in javascript are made up of key-value pairs, which is not the case here. The error is occurring here:

```
data = {items: [{ "4","5","6" }, {"7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"}]}
                     ^
```

The interpreter is expecting a colon `:` character whereas you give a comma. You may want to use an array instead.

Furthermore, you need to access the items array via `data.items` rather than `items` directly:

```js
data = {items: [[ "4","5","6" ], ["7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"]]}
console.log("items:", data.items[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax issue. In the list of items you have elements like `{ "4","5","6" }`, but this is not the correct syntax. For a list of items you want to put them between `[]` symbols; `{}` symbols are used for objects.

With that in mind, this is probably what you are trying to create:

`data = {items: [[ "4","5","6" ], ["7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"]]}`